# Magento 2 : Getting Error on Frontend After Upgrade

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade

I have upgraded the Magento version from 2.3.5-p1 to the Latest Magento Version: 2.4.3, and I am getting this error on frontend: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeLbp.png

when I have checked the error log file
(system.log),

then getting this error:

```
[2021-10-08 09:47:35] main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function isAllow() on null in /var/www/html/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/sidebar.phtml:1
```

Please, anyone, have the solution then help me for the same.

Comment: Have you try to copy wishlist from the default magento2.4.3 ad replace into this upgrade and then check.

Comment: Yes, I have copied that from the latest one but not works..Thank You So Much For the Idea.